# How to find a file with partially specified path?

Tags: bash, find, darwin

I am trying to find all my `.txt` and `.csv` files in my backup (Apple's time machine).

The structure of the backup directories is like this:

```
/machine name/date/Macintosh HD/
```

The above contains all the files from my machine on that day. I have many of those directories as the backup drive contains stuff from multiple machines, last 3 years.

What I am interested in is to find *my* text and CSV files so for example file:

> /mac1/2014-08-31-173253/Macintosh HD/**Users/me**/Documents/work/**file1.txt**

So I need to find all `.txt` files which have somewhere on their path **/Users/me**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `find`, provided it's available:

```
$ find "/mac1/2014-08-31-173253/Macintosh HD" -wholename "*/Users/me/*.txt" -or -wholename "*/Users/me/*.csv"
```

This will search `/mac1/2014-08-31-173253/Macintosh HD` for files containing the pattern `*/Users/me/*.(txt|csv)` in their paths.

Comment: `... \( -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.csv' \) -a -wholename '*/Users/me/*'` should be more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you can just do:

```
set --
for d in /mac[123]/201[1-4]*'/Macintosh HD/Users/me/Documents/work/'
do  for g in .txt .csv
do  set -- "$d"*"$g"
    [ -e "$1" ] || shift
done
```

In that way you'd get an array of all of the file names in `"$@"` - but you'd need to glob the directory bit - which is what the `/mac[123]/` is for, and I'm only guessing at the names of those directories.